# CodeMirror: Is it possible to pass \ register a mode as a delegate function?

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I need to change values of tokens dynamically, using custom mode that i wrote.
is it possible to change modes by passing delegate function of the mode, or maybe there is a better way.
I am implementing codemirror using angular 2.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can wrap a mode to create another mode. See for example the yaml-frontmatter mode in the distribution, or the mode/multiplex and mode/overlay addons.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have found the modes in the distribution and tried to search about the usage of them but still i don`t understand how can i change tokens dynamically,
my goal is to let the user choose words / symbols that will be marked inside the text area.
is it possible the get a refference to some source that implement that behavior?